# android studio use JNI to build c/c++ ,but the c/c++ need another lib.a, how to solve

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

about the android studio. when I edit JNI to using c/c++ code ，but the c/c++ code using another lib .a, so how could I edit my CMakeList.txt，please help me, if you are good at using Android Studio[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phQeI.png)

this is my CMakeList.txt
when I make project . it says about "/../../mips64el-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lwebsockets"

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

aux_source_directory(src/main/cpp/android_src/common FILE_COMMON)
aux_source_directory(src/main/cpp/android_src FILE_SRC)
aux_source_directory(src/main/cpp/ FILE_CPP)
SET(ALL_FILE ${FILE_CPP} ${FILE_SRC} ${FILE_CPP})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src/main/cpp/cpp_include)
#LINK_DIRECTORIES(src/main/cpp/cpp_lib)
add_library( websockets STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(websockets PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/cpp/cpp_lib/libwebsockets.a)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             #native-lib
             SkylightWebSocket

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             #src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             ${ALL_FILE})


find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       #native-lib
                       SkylightWebSocket

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       libwebsockets.a ${log-lib})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **libwebsockets.a**, use **websockets** in the `target_link_libraries()` statement.

To make it easier to understand, here is an edited script:

```
add_library( Q STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Q PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/cpp/cpp_lib/libwebsockets.a)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         #native-lib
         SkylightWebSocket

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         #src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
         ${ALL_FILE})

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   #native-lib
                   SkylightWebSocket

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   Q log)
```

Note that with NDK, **log** library is defined, you don't need `find_library` at all.

Comment: Thank you! But it did not work. There is a new error : error: 'src/main/cpp/cpp_lib/libwebsockets.a', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/mips64/libSkylightWebSocket.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: Thank you! But it did not work. There is a new error :                             
{error: 'src/main/cpp/cpp_lib/libwebsockets.a', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/mips64/libSkylightWebSocket.so', missing and no known rule to make it  }     .but  the libwebsockts.a  does  not need to be made.    it is already a static lib (libwebsockets.a).  Is there something wrong ?

Comment: I bet you need to tune your **abiFilters**. Check what ABI the prebuilt library supports. Regarding the libwebsockets.a file, look for it and fix the path. 'no known rule to make it' means that the path you provided is wrong.